# Getting the error undefined is not a function (near '...prevtOrder.map...')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get data from firebase firestore database and display the data in React native. But when I loop through the data using map, it is showing me this error.

The below is the code for fetching the data from firestore.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = db.collection("orders").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      setPrevOrder(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        items: doc.data().items,
        restaurantName: doc.data().restaurantName
      })))
       
    
   })
   
   return unsubscribe
   
   
 },[])
```

The below is the code where I am trying to loop through the state variable and displaying it.

```
{
    <View>
    {
        prevOrder && prevOrder.map((order,index) => (
            <Text key = {index}>{order.restaurantName}</Text>
        ))
    }
    </View>
}
```

Is there a way to solve this

Comment: Are you mapping through an array?

Comment: Yes I am using the state array
` const [prevOrder, setPrevOrder] = useState([])`

Comment: share a working link if you can..

Comment: and looks like you are only setting objects in prevOrder.

Comment: I think it worked just now, before it was wrongly set as `const [prevOrder, setPrevOrder] = useState({})`.  When I changed {} to [] it worked.  Anyway Thank you for the help.